# Show selection bases on previous selection, using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, odbc

I'm trying to dis[play a list of addresses for a selected customer. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php 
$customer_table = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblSalesCustomers";
$customer_result = odbc_exec($conn, $customer_table);


 ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Address1" class="col-md-4 control-label">Customer:</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">

     <?php
        echo ' <select class="form-control" id="cstmC" name="cstmC">';

         while($row4 = odbc_fetch_array($customer_result))
    {
        echo"  <option value='".$row4['CustomerID'] . "'>" . $row4['CustomerName'] ."</option>";
    }
        echo'</select>';
        ?>
      </div>                                    
    </div>
  </div>


    <?php 

    $AddressIDC = $_POST['cstmC'];

$address_table = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblSalesAddress WHERE CustomerID LIKE '".$AddressIDC."'";
$address_result = odbc_exec($conn, $address_table);


 ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Address1" class="col-md-4 control-label">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">

     <?php
        echo ' <select class="form-control" id="adress" name="address">';

         while($row6 = odbc_fetch_array($address_result))
    {
        echo"  <option value='".$row6['AddressID'] . "'>" . $row6['AddressName'] ."</option>";
    }
        echo'</select>';
        ?>
      </div>                                    
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I remove the LIKE clause in the address_table query, all of the addresses for all customers are displayed. Does anyone know how I can display addresses, linked to the selected customer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put this select inside a form and put a submit button in it with some minor tweaks and it will work. If you want it without page loading and without form use ajax for that.

Comment: If you want to display the address of the selected customer, in the select clause,add where customer id = selected customer id

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I added CustomerID = SELECTED CustomerID but nothing happened, have you got an example query please?